# Button on the win CE 6.0 device

Tags: c#, windows, compact-framework, .net-2.0, windows-ce

On your device running win CE 6.0 is a button, and you need to catch the moment when it is pressed. That is, until we press the button, our method is performed, released - stop method. Please help with the solution of the problem.

Comment: What sort of "button"?  Hardware or software?

Comment: Then it depends *greatly* on the hardware.  What hardware, exactly, is this?

Comment: Chinese device for reading RFID. I have an application that works while in this mode - I press the button - the method is executed, shake again - the method stops executing.

Comment: Ask the OEM how to get button presses from the device.  It's likely that only they know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to codeproject with source code to do what you want:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49881/Hooking-the-keyboard-message-queue-in-compact-fram

I have used this code successfully in my own WM project to re-purpose volume keys and a few other hardware buttons (I use volume up/down on one screen as a trigger to flip the screen orientation).

There is too much code to post here. in the project is vkmap.cs which appears to be a comprehensive listing of all the keys available:

```
   public static vkMap[] vkValues = {
            new vkMap ( 0x00, "VK_NOTDEF"), 
            new vkMap ( 0x01, "VK_LBUTTON" ),
            new vkMap ( 0x02,"VK_RBUTTON" ),
            new vkMap ( 0x03,"VK_CANCEL" ),
...
            new vkMap ( 0x30,"VK_0" ),
            new vkMap ( 0x31,"VK_1" ),
...
            new vkMap ( 0x41,"VK_A" ),
...
            new vkMap ( 0xA6,"VK_BROWSER_BACK" ),
            new vkMap ( 0xA7,"VK_BROWSER_FORWARD" ),
            new vkMap ( 0xA8,"VK_BROWSER_REFRESH" ),
```

and so on.. all in all some 258 keys however some are marked as undefined.

To use the code:

```
HookKeys hook = new HookKeys();
hook.HookEvent += new HookKeys.HookEventHandler(HookEvent);
hook.Start();
```

Then in your eventHandler code as you wish - I used a Switch statement to find the keys I wanted:

```
     switch (vkMap.vkValues[keyBoardInfo.vkCode].s)
        {
            case "VK_F6":
                if ((hookArgs.wParam.ToInt32() == WM_KEYDOWN) || (hookArgs.wParam.ToInt32() == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
                // Code here
                break;
            case "VK_F7":
                if ((hookArgs.wParam.ToInt32() == WM_KEYDOWN) || (hookArgs.wParam.ToInt32() == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
                 // Code here
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

I can't recall why i'm also checking WM_KEYDOWN and WM_SYSKEYDOWN.. sorry about that; If I remember i'll post an edit.

And when you're finished needing input:

```
hook.Stop();
```

Comment: This may or may not work, depending on how the OEM mapped the button.  If it's mapped as a keyboard button, then this will work.  If it's not a keyboard button (and I've seen plenty of CE devices with buttons that weren't) then this won't work.

Comment: Agree, but still a great code sample referenced that I hadn't seen before for +1 for that